# How to change Next/Image according to screen size?

Tags: web, next.js, next-images

I have a hero with multiple images, I want to display images according to screen sizes, for example, if the user is using a big screen, the hero will load the large/wide images, and if he uses a phone, the hero will display a different image that is not wide to fit the screen.
I do not know how to do this with nextjs, there is no way to specify which image to load on a different screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did solve the problem using nextjs's useMediaQuery
{ const mobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm')); }, but the results aren't perfect, because if you use mobile ? [....] : [....] you cannot add 'priority' to the image components, if you try to add it, it will load both images first, then execute the conditional statement to hide one. so you have to sacrifice that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `Image` doesn't support that use case. I found this and it works as expected.  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32196#discussioncomment-1761938

Answer (score 2):

It's sad that this is not supported by `next/image`. What we can do for now is to use the native `picture` html element. Now that in NextJS 13 the Image component is not wrapped by any `div` or `span` wrapper anymore, we can now do the ff:

```
<div className="image-container">
 <picture>
   <source media="(max-width: 37.5em)" srcSet="mobile-img.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 62em)" srcset="desktop-img.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" srcset="tablet-img.jpg">
   <Image src="desktop-img.jpg" alt="alt text here" fill />
 </picture>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but what I did was create a new next/image component right next to the original one, but with the additional attribute of

```
media="(min-width: 1440px)"
```

I dont know if this is a proper optimized solution, it might be a bit janky but it works for me. In my case I only have two images, where one is mobile/tablet and the other is for desktop.

edit: nevermind that did not work, coincidentally it appeared to work but it just hid the second image behind it. fixed it by giving new classes,and change display to none or block to hide and unhide it

```
@media (width<= 1439px) {
   .image {
       ...
   }
   .image2 {
       display: none
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `useMediaQuery()` method from Material UI,
but it didn't seem SEO-friendly and was also a bit laggy

So this is a more straightforward, more responsive way of doing it
**Also, this is the method used by most of the websites**

```
import Image from "next/image"

export function DynamicImage({ src = "", mobileOnlySrc = "" }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Image src={src} fill className={`${(mobileOnlySrc !== "") ? 'hidden lg:block' : ''}`} />
            {(mobileOnlySrc !== "") && (
                <Image src={mobileOnlySrc} fill className={`${(mobileOnlySrc !== "") ? 'lg:hidden' : ''}`} />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to control the width and height on the parent component, make it relative and the use the property `fill={true}` on the Image component.

```
       <div className="relative h-32 w-32">
         <Image
           src={"/default-profile-picture.png"}
           fill={true}
           alt="Profile picture"
         />
       </div>
```